# Advanced Find and Replace Based off What is Found - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simplify a process with a script. What is happening is I have a decent size script that has lots of base-64 encoded strings, and I would like to replace them with the decoded version (using `atob` and `btoa`). For example, I have `atob("MHhfZXhwb3J0")` and would like to replace it with the output of `atob("MHhfZXhwb3J0")`, which is `"0x_export"`. I have tried splitting the code for `atob("`, then saving the contents and replacing them, but for some reason it breaks at some point. I have tried using `string.replace(/*/g, *)`, but it seems that you cannot use functions in replace. I am sorry if I am not the best at describing my question, so if anyone has further question, I would be glad to reply.

A small example of what I am trying to do is shown below:

The beginning example script:

```js
function test(callback, number, reason) {
    if (number != atob("MA==")) {
        console.log(atob("RmFpbGVkOiA=") + reason + atob("LiBQbGVhc2UgdHJ5IGFnYWluLg=="));
    } else {
        callback(number);
    }
}
```

The afterwards example script:

```js
function test(number, reason) {
    if (number != "0") {
        console.log("Failed: " + reason + ". Please try again.");
    } else {
        callback(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* pass functions to replace - you can paste the whole code into some Javascript editor as a string, and then `replace` every instance of `atob("...")` with the decoded text:

```js
const inputScript = `
function test(callback, number, reason) {
    if (number != atob("MA==")) {
        console.log(atob("RmFpbGVkOiA=") + reason + atob("LiBQbGVhc2UgdHJ5IGFnYWluLg=="));
    } else {
        callback(number);
    }
}
`;
const outputScript = inputScript
  .replace(/atob\("([^\"]+)"\)/g, (_, p1) => `"${atob(p1)}"`)
  .trim();
console.log(outputScript);
```

Comment: Wow! I did not know that this was possible! This worked better than anything I expected! I am for sure going to use this a lot! Thanks for the answer! 
A question however is why do most websites say that this is either not possible or must use `RegExp`?

Comment: What do you mean, which websites say that? I guess they're wrong.